# Airodump-ng : why are BSSID not associated?

Tags: network, wireless, aircrack-ng, airodump-ng

Using airodump-ng with my wireless adapter in monitor mode, I am able to get expected scan to run.

[image]

I have a few questions :

- Why do BSSIDs show as "not associated" (note: not all of them show as such, some just show a usual BSSID)
- If I understand correctly, the STATION BSSIDs are access points to which the clients are connected, why are they not showing up with the above AP list? Are they simply not in range?

Answer (score 3):

> If I understand correctly, the STATION BSSIDs are access points to which the clients are connected,

You are correct.

> why are they not showing up with the above AP list?

From the [airodump-ng documentation](https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=airodump-ng) describing the "BSSID" field:

```
 MAC address of the access point. In the Client section, a BSSID of
 “(not associated)” means that the client is not associated with any
 AP. In this unassociated state, it is searching for an AP to connect
 with.
```

So typically the application has detected the client by hearing it send probe requests trying to find nearby wireless networks.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to understand all of this.

- STATIONS (clients mac addresses) have "not associated" BSSID (AP mac address) when the said clients are looking for wifi but have not yet connected to an AP.